# In Django, how to limit entries from each user to a specific number N (N > 1)?

Tags: python, database, django

I have a Django web  application that's similar to the typical Q&A system.

A user asks a question. other users submit answers to that question:

- Each user is allowed to submit up to N answers to each question,
  where N > 1 (so, say each user can submit no more than 3 answers to
  each question)
- A user can edit his existing answers, or submit new answer(s) if he
  hasn't already reached his limit.

It's straightforward to do this if each user is allowed only 1 answer
- just do:

```
unique_together = (("user.id", "question_id"),)
```

But in case of N>1, what is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add the following method to your Question model:

```
class Question(models.Model):

    def can_answer(self, user):
        return Answer.filter(question=self, user=user).count() < 3
```

You can use this method to decide if a user can add answers to the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a business rule that you will have to enforce at the application level rather than the  database level. Hence you will have to check at the time of answering if the user can indeed post an answer. This can be done in multiple ways. Andrey's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470120/in-django-how-to-limit-entries-from-each-user-to-a-specific-number-n-n-1/3470288#3470288) is one way of doing this. Another way would be to check for this during `Answer.save()`. If you prefer to keep the logic away from models you can define an utility function `can_answer(user, question)` that returns `True` or `False` and invoke it from the view.